# Maven Surefire plugin throwing class not found exception for EclipseStarter

Tags: maven, classnotfoundexception, surefire

We are running tests via `surefire plugin` for maven. It executes non OSGI specific tests successfully, but when it comes to OSGI specific tests it throws an exception stating:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/EclipseStarter
```

The complete stack trace is:

```
Test set: com.project.handler.impl.BeanOsgiIntegrationTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.022 sec <<< FAILURE!
testOsgiBundleContext(com.project.handler.impl.BeanOsgiIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/adaptor/EclipseStarter
    at org.springframework.osgi.test.platform.EquinoxPlatform.start(EquinoxPlatform.java:74)
    at org.springframework.osgi.test.AbstractOsgiTests.startup(AbstractOsgiTests.java:237)
    at org.springframework.osgi.test.AbstractOsgiTests.prepareTestExecution(AbstractOsgiTests.java:374)
    at org.springframework.osgi.test.AbstractOsgiTests.runBare(AbstractOsgiTests.java:203)
    at org.springframework.osgi.test.AbstractOsgiTests$1.protect(AbstractOsgiTests.java:184)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at org.springframework.osgi.test.AbstractOsgiTests.run(AbstractOsgiTests.java:181)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.IsolatedClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedClassLoader.java:97)
    ... 55 more
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Have you checked the maven classpath? You can use `mvn dependency:build-classpath` to print the complete classpath.

Comment: What should I check in the classpath?

Comment: Which jar contains the missing class? You need to check whether this jar is present in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I added following dependency into the pom file and the issue got resolved, I was expecting surefire have this dependency, as this is required by surefire <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: Surefire uses that class only indirectly. The question is probably why the artifact of `AbstractOsgiTests` does not have this dependency.

Comment: spring-osgi-test-1.0.2 has it, but with the scope "provided", probably that is the reason, it did not download on my machine  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi</artifactId>
      <version>${equinox.ver}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>